# blockchain implementation not working while using sha256

Tags: javascript, blockchain

I am using this code to implement blockchain.

```
const sha256 =require('crypto-js/sha256');


class block{

   constructor(timestamp,nonce,value,prevhash)
   {
       this.timestamp=timestamp;
       this.nonce=nonce;
       this.value=value;
       this.prevhash=prevhash;
   } 
    calculate(){
   return String(sha256(this.timestamp,this.nonce,this.value,this.prevhash));
    }


}
const block1=new block(22,345,"changebro",345);
const block2 =new block(4385,545,45,2)
console.log(block1.calculate());
console.log(block1);
console.log(block2.calculate());
console.log(block2);
```

why the ans for both is coming same.

for both I am getting same ans
4ea5c508a6566e76240543f8feb06fd457777be39549c4016436afda65d2330e

Comment: This is not really about `blockchain`

Comment: Why do you think `crypto-js/sha256` expects an undefined number of arguments?

Comment: Are you sure it's identical? Also, try concatenating the values you pass to `sha256`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.